# IMS vs SCORM: Advantages and Disadvantages

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I've read that use of SCORM is more preferable than IMS specifications. So I wanted to know what are main advantages SCORM has over IMS Content packaging? Does end user find differences between both the packages while using it in every case and if not, then is it advantageous to migrate from IMS to SCORM specification. This is what I have read somewhere:

> "The key, mandatory difference between Scorm and IMS packaging is that
>   in Scorm, each resource must be given an attribute of ScormType, to
>   equal either "sco" or "asset". "sco" means that the resource supports
>   the Scorm runtime protocol, allowing it to exchange data with the
>   learning platform as it runs (marks, state, preference, communications
>   etc.). So from the user's point of view, packaging brings no benefits,
>   except that it makes the content transferrable to other systems. It is
>   in supporting the runtime (and, if you like, sequencing -another
>   add-on) that the user starts to see the benefit."

So can anyone please explain that what does it mean by "transferable to the other systems" and are IMS contents not transferable and how user can start seeing the benefits?
Thanking you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMS vs SCORM isn't really an apples-to-apples comparison; IMS is an organization which has sponsored many different specifications, such as Common Cartridge (which uses SCORM!) and IMS Question and Test Interoperability (QTI).  SCORM, on the other hand, is a collection of specifications bundled together by Advanced Distributed Learning (ADL), a U.S. government-funded organization.

In common practice, corporate LMSs will use either SCORM or AICC for course-to-LMS communication, whereas IMS's assorted specifications tend to be more common in the higher education market (used by higher-ed focused LMSs such as Blackboard, Sakai, etc.).

Since you haven't provided context for your question -- what audience are you developing for: Corporate training? College students? Something else? -- we can't really provide any guidance as to which one is best for your situation.

Side note: This is probably an appropriate time to mention the new [Tin Can API](http://tincanapi.com/), which is more flexible than SCORM, and provides a new approach for tracking both formal and informal learning.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I've to develop a tool for converting from IMS Content Package to SCORM Content package. My learning content contains some quiz questions (higher education). So I wanted to know, Is there difference in the users point of view and if not then how is it beneficial from converting from IMS CP to SCORM CP? As in my question I've quoted that it is beneficial but I didn't understand the reason given. In forum I read a problem that one guy is having many projects in IMS specification but his college wants to move from moodle to SLK, which doesn't support IMS.

Comment: So in the situation above is it beneficial to convert automatically from IMS to SCORM, rather than developing the project from scratch?

Comment: again, IMS is an organization, so there's no such thing as converting IMS to SCORM. One of IMS's flagship products is Common Cartridge, which uses SCORM as part of its packaging. You need to be specific about the IMS package -- what is it? QTI? Common Cartridge? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. Well, I've used 'Exe-Learning' tool to built my packages. In that tool I wrote some quiz questions and then exported them as 'IMS Content Package' and 'SCORM 1.2' but it didn't specify whether its QTI or not but its not Common Cartridge because there is a separate option for that.

Comment: In both the exported IMS Content Package and SCORM Package, there is imsmanifest.xml file, xsd files, web content and javascripts. SCORM has one extra xsd file adlcp one and two more javascripts APIWrapper and SCOFunctions. While in manifest SCORM had adlcp:scormtype='sco' attribute.

Comment: If I develop a True-False Quiz and export them as either IMS CP or SCORM CP then there is no difference in users point of view. While if I develop a SCORM Quiz(there is an option) and export as SCORM1.2, then user can get the calculated score after submitting, which is not available in the prior case.

Comment: One more thing I want to clarify that both the content packages can be uploaded on Moodle and work well under IMS Content Package category or SCORM pakage activity category. So I didn't understand whats the difference when both of them have no difference in users point of view or in uploading on LMS. I've read that presence of 'sco' and additional ECMASCripts make SCORM package more beneficial but can you please explain how? Thanks.

Comment: SCORM is a collection of specifications bundled together. One of the SCORM "books" is the content aggregation model (CAM), which uses the IMS Learning Resource Meta-data Information Model specification created by the IMS.  For more about SCORM packaging, see http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/content-packaging/ and http://www.adlnet.gov/capabilities/scorm#tab-learn